# Can't show an white text over an svg image

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg image behind a text, the image has a transparency and I want to text to have the color `white` but I don't know why I can't see the text only if I change the color to `black`. I want to know what I can do beside the option to convert the image to a format without the transparency.

Here is a fiddle with the code http://jsfiddle.net/rgaop03c/3/

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/72b.svg" alt="Hand" style="position: absolute;/* width: 303px; */height: 100%;bottom: 0px;right: 0px;z-index: 0;">
  <div class="info_text" style="width: 870px;text-align: center;font-size: 21px;line-height: 2;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);margin: 0px auto;">Random text right here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your text is behind the image. Use `position:relative` to bring it in front.

Comment: Thank you, that was is the answer. I tried with `z-index: -1`, but did not worked for me, but `position:relative` is the solution that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z-index: -1 does the trick.

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/72b.svg" alt="Hand" style="position: absolute;/* width: 303px; */height: 100%;bottom: 0px;right: 0px;z-index: -1;">
  <div class="info_text" style="width: 870px;text-align: center;font-size: 21px;line-height: 2;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);margin: 0px auto;">Imbunatatim deja constant serviciile online, oferind clientilor nostri functii avansate de identificare a ofertelor imobiliare cautate. Ne-am dedicat dezvoltarii continue de concepte si instrumente noi, care sa ofere tuturor un grad ridicat de incredere in serviciile si echipa imocentral.ro.</div>
</div>
```

You could also set z-index: 1 on div class="info_text" . But note this: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Answer (score 0):

Change `z-index: 0;` to `z-index: -1;`

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/72b.svg" alt="Hand" style="position: absolute;/* width: 303px; */height: 100%;bottom: 0px;right: 0px;z-index: -1;">
  <div class="info_text" style="width: 870px;text-align: center;font-size: 21px;line-height: 2;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);margin: 0px auto;">Random text right here</div>
</div>
```